# Spring Boot 1 database multiple database users

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am currently building a restful API (with Spring Boot) that accesses a database. This application will eventually be hosted on a server.

What I would like to do:

1. Configure the database with multiple users, and assign them
   different rights to different tables
2. Depending on which endpoint is called, use a specific user to execute that queries within that function

How do I go about configuring the application above?

The answers I've found so far involve configuring multiple datasources, but for the above application, there is only one datasource, but multiple users.

I have read the following link but am still trying to understand it

https://kimrudolph.de/blog/spring-datasource-routing

Do I configure multiple datasources all with the same URL (jdbcURL in this case), and multiple sets of usernames and passwords for each role?

Thank you!

Comment: Regarding your question: Yes, I would do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already found the best way to do that task, I mean `AbstractRoutingDataSource`. If you have fixed number of users it is the simplest way you could use following approach:

```
public final class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return UserContextHolder.getUserName() + "DataSource";
    }
}
```

And configuration:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("user1DataSource")
public DataSource userOneDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .username("user1")
            .password("pass")
             ...
             .build();
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("user2DataSource")
public DataSource userOneDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .username("user2")
             ...
             .build();
}

@Bean
@Primary
public RoutingDataSource dataSource(Map<String, DataSource> datasources) {
    return new RoutingDataSource().dataSource(datasources);
 }
```

If you need add users and datasources at runtime you could use somethig like this:

```
public final class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, DataSource> dynamicDataSources = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return UserContextHolder.getUserName() + "_datasource";
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource determineTargetDataSource() {
        String currentLookupKey = this.determineCurrentLookupKey().toString();
        String userName = UserContextHolder.getUserName();
        String password = UserContextHolder.getPassword();

        return this.dynamicDataSources.computeIfAbsent(currentLookupKey, (key) -> DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName("your.driver.class")
                .url("jdbc:same:url/here")
                .username(userName)
                .password(password)
                .build());
    }
}
```